# RamdaJS How to use R.find with R.or?

Tags: ramda.js

I'm still cutting my teeth on ramda and struggling with the basics.

I want to find the first object that has any of many properties set.  So I'm trying to use a find with an or, but no matter how I construct it I cannot seem get it to work.  [repl.it](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?var%20xs%20%3D%20%5B%7Ba%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7Bb%3A%202%7D%2C%20%7Ba%3A%203%7D%5D%3B%0AR.find%28R.or%28R.prop%28%27c%27%29%2C%20R.prop%28%27b%27%29%29%29%28xs%29%3B%0A%0A)

```
var xs = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {a: 3}];
R.find(R.or(R.prop('c'), R.prop('b')))(xs);
```

I was expecting this to evaluate to {b:2} but it keeps returning undefined.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you will want [`R.either`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#either) which takes two boolean producing functions, while `R.or` is just expecting two boolean values to compare (effectively a curried form of `(a, b) => a || b`).

Comment: Combining this with the answer from @customcommander, we get `find(either(has('c'), has('b')))(xs)`, which is probably as simple as you;re going to get with Ramda.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `prop` to test whether an object has a property as it would return a false negative if a property is set to a falsy value. (Use `has` instead.) Also if you have more than two conditions you may want to consider using `anyPass` instead of `either`.

```js
const findObject =
  R.find(R.__, [
    {a: 0},
    {b: 1},
    {c: 1}]);


// probably not the result you expected
findObject(
  R.anyPass([
    R.prop('a'),
    R.prop('b')])); //=> {b: 1}

// most likely the result you expected
findObject(
  R.anyPass([
    R.has('a'),
    R.has('b')])); //=> {a: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: R.__ (two underscores; not one) doesn't seem to be documented on its own. However it's explained in [R.curry](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry). It's a placeholder parameter for curried functions allowing you to specify parameters later on. For example `R.pair(1, 2)` and `R.pair(R.__, 2)(1)` will both return `[1, 2]`. It's a very useful thing to add to your functional kit.